# Using Calculus to show that a relation matching the intention of The Principal Square Root is a function.

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

I want to formalize the notion of "**The Principal Square Root Function**" using calculus and wondered if this approach was correct.

---

Define the *relation* $\sqrt{\cdot}$ as $\left\{\langle x,y \rangle \in \mathbb R_{\geq 0} \times \mathbb R_{\geq 0} \ | \ y^2=x \text{ and } y\geq0\right\}$. The objective it to show that this relation has only one output for a given input.

First, two lemmas and their proofs:

> The function $(\cdot)^2: \mathbb R_{\geq 0}  \to \mathbb R_{\geq 0} $ is surjective $\quad (\dagger_1)$

> The function $(\cdot)^2: \mathbb R_{\geq 0}  \to \mathbb R_{\geq 0} $ is injective $\quad (\dagger_2)$

---

**Lemma $1$**

To prove $(\dagger_1)$, first note that $(\cdot)^2$ is a continuous function. Next, consider any $\alpha \geq 0$. If $\alpha=0$, then we know that $\alpha^2=0=\alpha$. So let's only consider $\alpha \gt 0$. Suppose $\alpha \gt 1$. Then we know that $\alpha^2 \gt \alpha$. By applying the *Intermediate Value Theorem* (IVT) to the interval $[0,\alpha]$, we know that there is an $x \in (0,\alpha)$ such that $x^2=\alpha$. Similarly, if $0 \lt \alpha \lt 1$, noting that $1^2=1$, then we can apply the IVT to $[0,1]$, and we will find an $x \in (0,1)$ such that $x^2=\alpha$. Finally, if $\alpha=1$, we know that for any $c \gt 1$, $c^2 \gt 1$, so apply the IVT to $[0,c]$, and we will have an $x \in (0,c)$ such that $x^2=\alpha$. In conclusion, $(\cdot)^2$ is surjective.

---

**Lemma $2$**

To prove $(\dagger_2)$, first note that $(\cdot)^2$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$. Setting $f=(\cdot)^2$, we have that $f'(x)=2x$. For $x \gt 0$, we have that $f'(x) \gt 0$. This means that on the interval $(0,\infty)$, $f$ is strictly increasing. Because $f$ is (right) continuous at $0$, we can state that on $[0,\infty)$, $f$ is strictly increasing. Therefore, $f=(\cdot)^2$ is injective on $[0,\infty)$.

---

**Main Proof**

To show that $\sqrt{\cdot}$ has only one output for a given input, consider an arbitrary $x \geq 0$. By $(\dagger_1)$, we know that any $x \geq 0$ has at least one square root $y \geq 0$ such that $y^2=x$. Further, by $(\dagger_2)$, we know that this is the *only* square root $\geq 0$ such that $y^2=x$.

As such, $\sqrt{x}=y$, unambiguously.

---

A similar approach can be taken to formalize the notion of "**The Cube Root Function**".

---

Define the *relation* $\sqrt[3]{\cdot}$ as $\left\{\langle x,y \rangle \in \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \ | \ y^3=x \right\}$. The objective it to show that this relation has only one output for a given input.

First, two lemmas and their proofs:

> The function $(\cdot)^3: \mathbb R  \to \mathbb R $ is surjective $\quad (\dagger_3)$

> The function $(\cdot)^3: \mathbb R  \to \mathbb R $ is injective $\quad (\dagger_4)$

---

**Lemma $1$**

To prove $(\dagger_3)$, first note that $(\cdot)^3$ is a continuous function. Next, consider any $\alpha \in \mathbb R$. First, suppose $\alpha=0$. Then we know that $\alpha^3=0=\alpha$. Let us now look at $\alpha \gt 0$.

Suppose $\alpha \gt 1$. Then we know that $\alpha^3 \gt \alpha$. By applying the *Intermediate Value Theorem* (IVT) to the interval $[0,\alpha]$, we know that there is an $x \in (0,\alpha)$ such that $x^3=\alpha$. Similarly, if $0 \lt \alpha \lt 1$, noting that $1^3=1$, then we can apply the IVT to $[0,1]$, and we will find an $x \in (0,1)$ such that $x^3=\alpha$. Finally, if $\alpha=1$, we know that for any $c \gt 1$, $c^3 \gt 1$, so apply the IVT to $[0,c]$, and we will have an $x \in (0,c)$ such that $x^3=\alpha$.

Next, suppose $\alpha \lt 0$. First, consider when $-1 \lt \alpha \lt 0$. Noting that $(-1)^3=-1$, apply the IVT to $[-1,0]$. Then there is an $x \in (-1,0)$ such that $x^3=\alpha$. Suppose $\alpha = -1$. Then for any $c \lt -1$, we have that $c^3 \lt -1$. As such, apply the IVT to the interval $[c,0]$. Then there is an $x \in (c,0)$ such that $x^3 = \alpha$. Finally, let $\alpha \lt -1$. Then we know that $\alpha^3 \lt -1$. Applying the IVT to $[\alpha,0]$, we know that there is an $x \in (\alpha,0)$ such that $x^3=\alpha$.

In conclusion, $(\cdot)^3$ is surjective.

---

**Lemma $2$**

To prove $(\dagger_4)$, first note that $(\cdot)^3$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$. Setting $f=(\cdot)^3$, we have that $f'(x)=3x^2$. For $x \gt 0$, we have that $f'(x) \gt 0$. This means that on the interval $(0,\infty)$, $f$ is strictly increasing. A similar argument shows that $f$ must be strictly increasing on the interval $(\infty,0)$. Because $f$ is continuous at $0$, we can state that on $(-\infty,0]$ and$[0,\infty)$, $f$ is strictly increasing, which means that on $(-\infty, \infty)$, $f$ is strictly increasing. Therefore, $f=(\cdot)^3$ is injective on $(-\infty,\infty)$.

---

**Main Proof**

To show that $\sqrt[3]{\cdot}$ has only one output for a given input, consider an arbitrary $x \in \mathbb R$. By $(\dagger_3)$, we know that any $x \in \mathbb R$ has at least one cube root $y$ such that $y^3=x$. Further, by $(\dagger_4)$, we know that this is the *only* cube root such that $y^3=x$.

As such, $\sqrt[3]{x}=y$, unambiguously.

---

**Special Note**

The format for the above two arguments is easily generalizable to two separate categories of $n$ for the relationship: $\sqrt[n]{\cdot} \quad:$ when $n$ is an even natural number and when $n$ is an odd natural number.

For the even $n$ category, define the relationship as: $\sqrt[n]{\cdot}=\left\{\langle x,y \rangle \in \mathbb R_{\geq 0} \times \mathbb R_{\geq 0} \ | \ y^n=x \text{ and } y\geq 0 \right\}$

For the odd $n$ category, define the relationship as: $\sqrt[n]{\cdot}=\left\{\langle x,y \rangle \in \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \ | \ y^n=x \right\}$

In conclusion, the standard uses of natural number roots can all be viewed as functions.

Comment: (*Principal* square root.)